# How can I read only 10 rows from my Sql Database?

Tags: java, android, sql, arrays, eclipse

Hey I have a question:) How can I read only ten rows from my sql db?
here is my code:

```
openDB();
 Cursor c = myDb.getSpalte();
 List<Integer> valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>(c.getCount());

 while (c.moveToNext()) {        
     valueList.add(c.getInt(1));

 }
 c.close();
 closeDB();
```

And if it helps you here is my getSpalte method:

```
public Cursor getSpalte(){
    String where = null;
    String Order = "_id DESC";
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_KALOA, 
            where, null, null, null, Order, null);
  if (c != null) {
  c.moveToFirst();
}
  return c;
}
```

Thank yout for helping! And sorry for my bad englsih;P

Comment: Follow this. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: but which ten rows do you want to read? first/last ten? or ten rows with some specific field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the last `null` argument to "10". This argument is for `LIMIT` which limits the number of rows returned by the query.

```
Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_KALOA, 
        where, null, null, null, Order, "10");
```

Remember though that limiting must be accompanied by appropriate logic to sort the result set. Otherwise, you can get any 10 rows, which may not always be what you want.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: And how can I do this in my other class? because sometimes I want only ten and some times all:)?

Comment: You could let your `getSpalte` method take a parameter - `null` to retrieve all and some numeric value to limit to that value, and pass that parameter in to `query` instead of hard-coding.

Comment: And how should that look like?

Comment: Signature `public Cursor getSpalte(string limit)` and in method body `query(.....,limit)`.

Comment: Ahh okayy Thank yout a lot!:)

Answer (score 0):

Change your db query in your getSpalte function like this:

```
Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_KALOA, 
        where, null, null, null, Order, "10");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using select TOP, limit or using ROWNUM depending on the DB you use, or you can simple handle it using a simple for loop instead of while.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` for that as last argument. Here 10.

[Refer here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

> limit -   Limits the number of rows returned by the query, formatted as
>   LIMIT clause. Passing null denotes no LIMIT clause.